# It doesnt open the Users Settings, System Settings

Tags: users, system-settings

Every time i click in Users Settings, in System Settings, it closes the window. A million times trying and it stills keep closing. 
Would somebody help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the latest updates in your system?

Open a terminal and do the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot you system and try again.

Comment: Well i will try it, later i will tell you the results

Comment: Did it work for you ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified logs `journalctl /usr/bin/gnome-shell -f -o cat`?

Se solution in my similar topic: [I cannot open system settings in ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1007378/i-cannot-open-system-settings-in-ubuntu-17-10/1007387#1007387)